# melting to bones on hunger strikes -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Source: [Putin Puts Heroic Female Pilot on Trial](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/12/13/putin-puts-heroic-female-pilot-on-trial.html)

Example:

> There are 10 Ukrainian cases in Russia at the moment, Svetova added, but Savchenko’s is the most well known by far. “She is the most famous political prisoner because she is a woman who is **melting to bones** on hunger strikes,” Svetova said.

I don't understand that. Specifically, the *melting to bones* part.

Comment: The phrasing sounds like it's a direct (or closely literal) translation from the Russian original. **Melting** *down* to *her* **bones**: slowly disappearing like butter on a hot skillet, or candle wax melts until there's nothing left except her bones (bones do not melt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are 10 Ukrainian cases in Russia at the moment, Svetova added, but Savchenko’s is the most well known by far. “She is the most famous political prisoner because she is a woman who is **melting to bones** on hunger strikes,” Svetova said.

It's figurative language. "A woman whose weight is **getting critically reduced** during her hunger strikes".

Nadiya Savchenko has attempted at least one hunger strike to protest her kidnapping and the unjust nature of the trial. I don't recall her starting other hunger strikes, but the quotation presents it as if she is attempting them again and again.

The one hunger strike that I recall resulted in her loosing all her body fat and some muscle tissue and assuming a "skin and bones" appearance. Her body fat "**melted to bones**", as it were. Using a clumsy paraphrase, her body was "*reduced to bone level*".

[image]

(from [Komsomolskaya Pravda Ukraine](http://kp.ua/politics/492609-posle-soobschenyi-o-smerty-nadezhdu-savchenko-vzialy-pod-usylennuui-okhranu): you can see the lineaments of her face sharpened as much of the body fat has wasted away)

---

She does not "melt to bones" in a literal sense, because if you **melt to bones** in a literal sense, you will have only your skeleton left: your bare bones. One example of such literal usage:

> Within minutes the dead animal had been **stripped to bones** – nothing left but head, tail and ribcage. ([Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?id=sIEX5XOf7MAC&lpg=PT34&ots=ac9iBWMozz&dq=stripped%20%22to%20bones%22&hl=ru&pg=PT34#v=onepage&q=stripped%20%22to%20bones%22&f=false); a description of an animal being cut up for meat by hungry people with knives)

---

P.S.

Compare with a more figurative expression:

> His ​comments ​**[reduced her to ​tears](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/you-reduced-me-to-tears-what-does-it-mean)**. ("Literally it means that the person is gone and nothing is left except his or her tears", according to an answer at ELU SE)